# Create file and include it as a resource

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild

Is it possible to configure MSBuild to create file and include it as a resource to the project before compilation?
I need a couple of `.png` files to be copied from external (non-project) folder to `\Resources\` project directory and be added to the project as I would do it manually. Just added files should be used as `Embedded resources` in currently compiling assembly.

Comment: You need to give more details if you want a precise answer! The answer is Yes.

Comment: I don't understand, you want to do that at Runtime? if not then you can set the files `Build Action ` property to `Resource` at the Desing time

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to include them as EmbeddedResource you can add this to your msbuild BeforeBuild target:

`<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <EmbeddedResource Include="D:\Images\*.png" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>`

It gets the external images and adds them to your assembly (verified with IL Spy)